# Slow DynamoDB for php session handling

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb

we're using DynamoDB in order to synchronize sessions between more than one EC2 machine under ELBs.

We noticed that this method slow down a lot the scripts.

Specifically, I made a js that calls 10 times 3 different php scripts on the server.

1) The first one is just an echo timestamp(); and takes about 50ms as roundtrip time.
2) The second one is a php script that connect through mysqli to the RDS MySQL and takes the same time (about 50-60ms).
3) The third script use the DynamoDB session keeping method described in official AWS documentation and takes about 150ms (3 times slower!!).

I'm cleaning the garbage every night (as documentation say) and the DynamoDB metrics seems OK (attached below).

The code I use is this:

```
use Aws\DynamoDb\DynamoDbClient;
use Aws\DynamoDb\Session\SessionHandler;
ini_set("session.entropy_file", "/dev/urandom");
ini_set("session.entropy_length", "512");
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 0);

require 'aws.phar';

$dynamoDb = DynamoDbClient::factory(array(
    'key'    => 'XXXXXX',
    'secret' => 'YYYYYY',
    'region' => 'eu-west-1'
));

$sessionHandler = SessionHandler::factory(array(
    'dynamodb_client' => $dynamoDb,
    'table_name'      => 'sessions',
    'session_lifetime'         => 259200,
    'consistent_read'          => true,
    'locking_strategy'         => null,
    'automatic_gc'             => 0,
    'gc_batch_size'            => 25,
    'max_lock_wait_time'       => 15,
    'min_lock_retry_microtime' => 5000,
    'max_lock_retry_microtime' => 50000,
));

$sessionHandler->register();

session_start();
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is it normal all that time to retrieve the session?

Thanks.

Comment: DynamoDB should have single-digit millisecond latencies if your servers are in the same region.

Comment: Of course, they are in the same region.

Comment: Same issue, it takes additionnal 56ms on each page. EC2 and DynamoDb on the same region.

Answer (score 1):

Copying correspondence from an AWS engineer in AWS forums: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=597493

> Here a couple things to check:
>
> 1. Are you running your application on EC2 in the same region as your DynamoDB table?
> 2. Have you enabled OPcode caching to ensure that the classes used by the SDK do not need to be loaded from disk and parsed each time your
>      script is run?
>
> Using a web server like Apache and connecting to a DynamoDB session
>   will require a new SSL connection to be established on each request.
>   This is because PHP doesn't (currently) allow you to reuse cURL
>   connection handles between requests. Some database drivers do allow
>   for a persistent connections between requests, which could account for
>   the performance difference.

If you follow up on the AWS forums thread, an AWS engineer should be able to help you with your issue. This thread is also monitored if you want to keep it open.